# How do I tell what the timestamp is for a frame in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, quicktime

I'm using VLC 2.2.6 without additional extensions and I'd like to know the time a frame occurs in a video file. I can move forward frame by frame with the `E` key. Here's an example:

[image: frame 97 and 98 - VLC]

The video file has an advancing red frame counter burnt into it. You can see that advancing from frame 97 to 98 advances the time indicator from `00:01` to `00:02`.

However, if I scrub around the video and try again, I get a different result:
[image: frame 101 and 102 - VLC]
Here, VLC advances from `00:01` to `00:02` on frames 101 and 102 instead.

By comparison, QuickTime Player consistently changes from `00:01` to `00:02`on frames 70 and 71.
[image: frame 70 and 71 - QuickTime Player]

I'm concerned that VLC's indication of the time varies with each try and that it's so far off from QuickTime Player. Is there an option I need to enable to get accurate and consistent time readings from VLC?

Comment: You could convert the video with ffmpeg into a sequence of jpg images or a huffyuv encoded video which you can open e.g. in virtualdub.

Comment: I did convert it into a series of PNGs with ffmpeg. I also looked at the packets (one per frame) with ffprobe. What's interesting is that the frame with the red `71` corresponds with a PTS of 1.5 s. It seems that QuickTime player is consistent but wrong while VLC is mostly right (the frame with the red `101` has a PTS 2.0 s) but inconsistent.

Comment: I also need a solution to this. I need to re-sync some subtitles and I need to get the exact time a frame is drawn on the screen. I think it's a simple request, but there are no known solutions so far.